# jquery IE object does not support this property or method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, modx

I am using the jquery browser reject plugin (http://jreject.turnwheel.com/) and ironically the only browser it doesn't work on is IE. I keep getting the error object does not support this property or method. The page is here: http://2013.rmspr.co.uk. I've tried the no conflict thing and it seemed to cause more problems. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It complains about $.reject(); So is it loaded?

Comment: the js file for that is loaded in the head section. It works in firefox..

Comment: In Chrome I get html instead of assets/js/vendor/zepto.js

Comment: i've commented that file out to see if there was any conflict with it.

Comment: Its not any conflict. Its something else

Comment: I also get out of date browser in Chrome 27.

Comment: It's enabled on chrome and firefox for testing purposes.

Comment: Does it support jquery 1.9.1

Comment: It seems it does or it would fail in Chrome and Fx

Answer (score 0):

This does not look right (I use answer to get the formatting) I see this in IE's debugger

```
$(function(){  $.reject(); 
});
$(document).ready(
function() {
$(".about-main").niceScroll();

}
);
```

I would expect

```
$(function(){  
  $.reject(); 
  $(".about-main").niceScroll();
);
```

assuming reject and niceScroll are loaded correctly

I also think you can remove

```
 document.write(<script src=' +
 ('proto' in {} ? 'assets/js/vendor/zepto' : 'assets/js/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
```

Comment: Not sure where you are seeing this but i have already changed this so that it's now at the top of the custom.js file..

Comment: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'reject' 
custom.js, line 3 character 1

Comment: I know. I see jQuery is having an issue with the code <script>
  document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? 'assets/js/vendor/zepto' : 'assets/js/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script>

Can you comment that out for me?

Comment: AH! You are calling reject TWICE

Comment: Where can you see it twice?

Comment: Hmm.. In IE I do see it. Let me double check

Comment: Well it seems it was the zepto code above causing the issue. Thats part of the standard foundation framework, but as im using jquery i don't think its needed?

Comment: I would think so too. But in the IE debugger I DO see the $reject outside the custom.js

Comment: I also have a long running script that alerted me 3 times now - you SERIOUSLY load too many scripts

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue, 
I have commented below code:

```
 <!--  document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? '/Content/jquery/vendor/zepto' : '/Content/jquery/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')-->
```

script is working correctly

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment to **another answer**, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation